# Search a word into all makefiles linux from terminal

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal, command

I'm using Ubuntu. I have to search the word "send" into multiple makefiles.
Suppose that all makefiles are into /home/mypath. I tried this command but doesn't work. Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

```
find /home/mypath/ -name Makefile &&  grep -r "send"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the below command to find for `send` keyword in all the `Makefiles` 
recursively.

```
find /home/mypath -name "Makefile" | xargs grep -r "send"
```

Here the `find` command list all the files with name `Makefile` under the specified directory. `xargs` command will pass all the files listed with serially to the `grep` command to search for the string `send`

Answer (score 0):

If your base path is the same, you can use `grep` only:

```
grep -rn --color "send" /home/mypath/Makefile
```

Answer (score 0):

The `find` command has an option to transfer the found file name to an exec command which is here grep. Important is that you give `{}` which will be replaced with the filename found by `find`. You need also the `\;` as end mark of your command given for the ' -exec' option for `find`.

```
 find /home/mypath -name Makefile -exec grep "what you search" {} \;
```